# Отрисовка спрайта перед переходом на следующий экран

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

Пытаюсь набыдлокодить игрушку по типу Кто хочет стать миллионером,вариант ответа наследуется от Actor, чтобы каждый раз при нажатии, в зависимости от верности ответа спрайт варианта ответа перерисовывается в соответствующий цвет(зеленый, оранжевый). Реализовал это с помощью разных регионов текстур(sprite,sprite2,sprite3). Проблема в том, что вариант не успевает отрисоваться, т.к. происходит переход на другой экран(с результатом). Как можно исправить? И есть ли способ получше менять спрайт актера, чем создавать в классе три разных.

```
A.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int
                pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        };
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            if(A.shit) {
                A.sprite = A.sprite2;
                A.sprite.setBounds(A.getX(), A.getY(), A.getWidth(), A.getHeight());
                A.sprite.setPosition(A.getX(), A.getY() + 7);

                game.setScreen(new MilResultScreen(game, A.shit));
                dispose();
            }
            else if(A.shit==false){
                A.sprite = A.sprite3;
                A.sprite.setBounds(A.getX(), A.getY(), A.getWidth(), A.getHeight());
                A.sprite.setPosition(A.getX(), A.getY() + 7);

                game.setScreen(new MilResultScreen(game, A.shit));
                dispose();
            }
            }
    });
```

Comment: К сожалению, не находит пакета android.os.handler, решил это тем, что внутри варианта ответа создал clicklistener, ктр отвечает за отрисовку, и в самом экране игры добавляю еще один listener на вариант, отвечающий за переход на экран результата, не уверен, что это правильно, но хоть работает

Comment: Внедрите таймер

Answer (score 0):

В простых викторинах для планирования задержки можно использовать объект Handler(пакет android.os.handler)

А именно метод PostDelayed класса Handler. В аргументах получает выполняемую задачу Runnable и величину задержки в миллисекундах.

```
            Handler handler;

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //ваш код, который воспроизводится во время задержки
                }
            }, 2000);// задержка 2 секунды
```

Другие примеры как использовать метод postDelayed() есть в гугле.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно выставить задержку загрузки, но я посоветую выставить задержку анимации в методе onStart()в новом Activity.